# How can all instances of a character be replaced in all of the elements of a List of strings in scala?

Tags: scala

Input

```
ListOfWords = ["A_new_day", "Happy_world"]
```

Desired Output

```
ListOfWords = ["A new day", "Happy world"]
```

I tried doing this using for loop and replaceAll() for each string element. 
Any way to do this using map() or some other way.

Comment: Just do the same thing you were doing already, but with map: `list.map(_.replaceAll("_", " "))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` or `replaceAll` together with `map`:

```
val l = List("A_new_day", "Happy_world")
println(l.map(_.replace("_", " ")))  //output: List(A new day, Happy world)
```